# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while using thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

So I am getting the error

```
[Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The code I am running is

```
import threading

def hello_world(a):
    threading.Timer(2.0, hello_world(a)).start() # called every minute
    print(a)
    print("Hello, World!")

hello_world('a')
```

I noticed that when there are no arguments in the `hello_world` function the error doesn't occur. But as soon as I need to pass in a parameter to the function I get the error. Can someone explain why that is the case and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `threading.Timer()` constructor expects the *function* and the *arguments to pass to that function* as separate parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer). The proper way to call it is this:

```
threading.Timer(2.0, hello_world, (a,)).start()
```

You can see that we refer to `hello_world` without calling it, and we list the parameters we want to pass separately in a 1-tuple `(a,)`.

The way you're *currently* doing it, it's evaluating `hello_world(a)` immediately, before it gets to the end of the expression, trying to figure out what the return value of `hello_world(a)` would be - as opposed to starting the timer and then evaluating the expression every time the timer goes off.

Comment: I have seen the same error with a simple print function, can anyone reproduce? `def print_path(path):     print("In Python")     print("Path:"+ path)     print("Out Python")     return True if __name__ == '__main__':     message = "Hey D"     print_path(message)`